# Почему после включения ЧПУ многие страницы выдают 404 ошибку?

Tags: wordpress, apache, http-status-code-404

На [сайте WP](http://35.170.225.58) сейчас включены ЧПУ.  Почему после включения ЧПУ многие страницы выдают 404 ошибку?

Вот так выглядит .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Bitnami Wordpress, AWS, Ubuntu

Comment: Что значит - включены ЧПУ? Каким образом? Какие страницы выдают 404?

Comment: А, увидел. А как сайт переносили?

Comment: Использовал плагин WP All in one import

Comment: А предыдущий вопрос что пропустили? Каким образом "включены"?

Comment: Админка --> Настройки --> Постоянные ссылки. Причем эта беда была еще на локалхосте, еще до переноса на сервер, тогда я думал, что виноват Denwer. На сервере стоит Bitnami Wordpress, может в этом дело?

Comment: Там 5 вариантов, какой из них вы называете ЧПУ?

Answer (score 1):

Все, я пофиксил эту проблему, ЧПУ ломал код находившийся в файле темы functions.php!

Comment: Что же это за ответ. Вы уж тогда код проблемный приведите, и объясните, причину, по которой он ломал ссылки.